# liquibase - how do you set the default value for a text[] array?

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

In Liquibase - How do I create a defaultValue for type of text[] in the changelog?

```
<column name="colname" type="text[]" defaultValue="'{None}'">
    <constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
```

Makes: ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"

```
<column name="colname" type="text[]" defaultValue="ARRAY['None']::text[]">
    <constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
```

Also did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: My code doesn't compile with text[].. Can you show me the property lists

Comment: sorry i don't work for that company anymore... i've got no source for this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHH i found it. there was another option called `defaultValueComputed`. Here is what worked:

```
<column name="colname" type="text[]" defaultValueComputed="'{None}'::text[]">
    <constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
```